# How find the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+n}\frac{1}{n(m+2n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

find the value
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+n}\dfrac{1}{n(m+2n)}$$

I think this is good problem,Thank you everyone

I find 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1+x^2)}}{1+x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+n}\dfrac{1}{n(m+2n)}$$

Comment: Do, $m,n$ grow together or for each value $n,m$ grows from $1\ \cdots\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have edit,Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+n} \frac{1}{n(m+2n)}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} (-x)^{m-1} \cdot \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n}}{n} \, dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x} \, dx.
\end{align*}

For the last integral, you can refer to [this site](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic54.html).